# Is there a method to set a typed array to zero?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

Is there a way to set every element of a Javascript [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript_typed_arrays) (i.e. a `Uint32Array`) to some value (something like the C function [memset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memset.html) would do)?

```
var foo = new Uint32Array(16384);
for (int i=0; i<foo.length; i++) {   // I want to do this without a for-loop
    foo[i] = 0xdeadbeef;
}
```

Comment: This is old now but (es5) `Uint32Array.prototype.fill = function(filler) { for(var i in this){this[i]=filler} }; foo.fill(0xdeadbeef);` or (es6) `foo.fill(0xdeadbeef);`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Generally, the answer in this case is going to be no.  In JavaScript you either declare things fully when you create them via literal syntax:

```
var Arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Or you assign values to them (via loops when necessary for sequences):

```
var Arr2 = Array(32);

for (var i = 0, j < Arr2.length; i < j; ++i) { Arr2[i] = 0xdeadbeef; }
```

JavaScript is a language that benefits from only accessing Arr2.length once when possible, so this syntax should net a performance benefit over other variations, but there's not a way to assign all positions in an array to a specific value other than undefined, which is what you get when you initialize with a size.

Comment: Setting the length of an array to some value greater than its current value does not create any additional properties, it just increases the value of the length property.

Comment: Typed arrays are actually initialized to zero, not 'undefined'.  (Indeed, they can't store "undefined".)

Comment: This answers seems to ignore that the question is about **typed** arrays.  That said, there still doesn't seem to exist a method for doing so.